# Algorithm Determining Time Complexity

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

For the following algorithm:

```
Given a non-empty string s and a dictionary wordDict containing a list of non-empty words, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words. You may assume the dictionary does not contain duplicate words

For example, given
s = "leetcode",
dict = ["leet", "code"].

Return true because "leetcode" can be segmented as "leet code".
```

I wrote the following code:

```
def word_break(s, word_dict)
    can_break?(s, word_dict, memo = {})
end

def can_break?(s, word_dict, memo)
    return true if s.empty?
    (0...s.length).each do |index|
        string_to_pass = s[index + 1...s.length]
        memo[string_to_pass] ||= can_break?(string_to_pass, word_dict, memo)
        return true if word_dict.include?(s[0..index]) && memo[string_to_pass]
    end
    false
end
```

My understanding of the analysis here is that we have the number of recursive calls scaling linearly with input string size (since we trim down the number of recursive calls using memoization), and each recursive call does N work (to scan through the array). Does this evaluate to O(N^2) time and O(N) space?  (**note the dictionary is an array, not a hash)**.

Comment: Paveł and I read your "array" reference in different ways.  Can you please clarify?  I take it as your input string, with your word list as a dictionary (hashed); Paveł takes it as your word list.  This alters the time complexity, based on the word-list look-up time.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good summary of the rationale; yes, you're correct.
From a theoretical standpoint, with memoization, each character needs to serve as starting point for `m` scans, where `m` is the distance to the nearer end of the string.  There are various scalar-level optimizations you can apply, but the complexity remains **O**(N^2)

Comment: Given 2(two) parameters with independent dimensions. As example is not well-designed it looks like O(M*N^2), where N==s.length and M==word_dict.size

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk: Where do you see a dependence on word_dict.size?  Remember, hash-index lookup is O(1), not O(M).

Comment: Remember, `word_dict` is `Array` and `Array#include?` is O(M) lookup

Comment: word_dict is an Array, not a hash!